# Mudar o wp_query nas páginas de detalhe de cada projeto consoante a opção seleccionada na página de projetos

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Na página de projetos, onde estão todos os projetos, tem uma opção(select option) para ordenar alfabeticamente e outra para ordenar cronologicamente.
Quando se vai para o detalhe de cada projeto tem um link para o projeto a seguir e outro link para o anterior.
Queria perguntar se é possível o projeto anterior e próximo estarem ordenados de acordo com a opção selecionada da página de projetos.

Página de projetos: http://alvarovarejao.com/designpublico/pt/projetos/

```
    <div class="row filterr">
<div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="ccc" class="alfabet" id="c1" value="1">
        <label for="c1">
            <?php 
                if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { echo " Alphabetical"; } else { echo " Alfabeticamente"; }
            ?>
        </label>
        <br>
    <input style="margin-top: 12px;" type="radio" name="ccc" id="c2" value="2">
        <label for="c2">
            <?php 
                if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { echo " Chronological"; } else { echo " Cronologicamente";} ?> 
        </label>
        <br>
    <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" name="ccc" id="c3" value="3" checked="checked">
        <label for="c3" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <?php 
                if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { echo " Random"; } else { echo " Aleatoriamente";} 
        ?>
        </label>
</div>
</div>



<div class="text">

<div id="primary" class="row projects projects-filter">

        <?php

        if(substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 4) == '127.' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1') {
            if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { $project = 47; } else { $project = 49; }
        } else {
            if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { $project = 69; } else { $project = 71; }
        }


    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $project ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile; 
    else :
        endif;
        ?>

</div>
</div>

<div class="text2" style="display: none;">
    <div id="primary" class="row projects projects-filter">



        <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC', 'cat' => $project ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    else :
        endif;
        ?>

</div>
</div>

<div class="text3" style="display: none;">
    <div id="primary" class="row projects projects-filter">



        <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $project ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();


            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    else :
        endif;
        ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possível é, mas depende de como as suas queries estão sendo feitas -
 principalmente a reordenação. Edite a pergunta colocando os trechos de código relevantes.

Comment: Coloquei o código onde se processa a ordenação na página de projetos. O problema é gravar a ordenação para que se mantenha no detalhe de cada projeto.